# Why sub type is not assignable to <T extends baseclass> generics in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Why I can't assign `Future<T> fut = Future.value(Student())` where as `Future<User> fut = Future.value(Student())` is possible.

```dart
void main() {}

class Test<T extends User> {   // <----- T extends User (which is base class for Student & Teacher)
  Future<T> fut = Future.value(Student());  // <----- Compiler error
  Future<User> fut2 = Future.value(Student());  // <----- works fine
}

class User {}

class Teacher extends User {}

class Student extends User {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not necessarily any relationship between `T` and `Student`.  You've only established that `T` and `Student` both derive from `User`.  For example, `T` could be `Teacher`; how would you assign a `Future<Student>` to a `Future<Teacher>`?

Comment: Ah, make sense. Then how do I achieve something like that? I mean, variable should be able to hold reference to either `Future<Teacher>` or `Future<Student>`? If the type is `Future<User>` it needs typecast  when I want to get Student or Teacher. Thanks

Comment: @manikanta I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your example unconditionally constructs a `Future<Student>`, so there's no reason to store it as anything else. Do you have a more detailed example of what you want?